# Black screen, can't even get to boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2

Ok, so I'm a noob. I just needed to install tails and I was going to be done with ubuntu. I burned the image to a DVD then restarted it to boot from tails. (Incase it might be related to anything the last couple times I tried restarting I had to force shut it down after about 10 minutes .) So I was on the boot menu and I couldn't figure out how to boot from it so I hit escape and then pressed enter a bunch of times on something called grub I think. I turned off my pc out of confusion after that and now I can't even get to the boot menu. I know enough about computers to know it's not a problem with my monitor.

-im also running win 8.1 on my pc, ubuntu is on a usb

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are in a Console. See link:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man4/console.4.html

try this command: startx

You might need to login first. In any case, something is wrong with the boot sequence.